# How can I remove the "\n" character in a large file with Python?

Tags: python, regex-group

I have a large .txt file containing numerous email addresses, but it also contains many unnecessary "\n" characters. I want to extract only the email addresses and remove any other characters.

To accomplish this, I have written a small script in Python.

```
import re

filename = "input.txt"
output_filename = "output.txt"
email_regex = r'\s*([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})\s*'

with open(filename, "r") as f, open(output_filename, "w") as out:
    for line in f:
        emails = re.findall(email_regex, line)
        for email in emails:
            out.write(email + "\n")
```

While the script successfully extracted regular email addresses, it encountered some difficulties with certain formats.

**As an example, suppose I have a line of data that reads "CC\nexample@example.com\n". When I run my code, the resulting output is "nexample@example.com", which is not what I intended. Rather, I would like the output to be "example@example.com" without the leading "n" character."**

Next, I tested another small Python script for a single email address, and the results were successful.

```
import re

string = "CC\nexample@example.com\n"
email_regex = r'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}'

email = re.search(email_regex, string).group()

print(email)
```

So I want to get same result from a large file. If you have a solution for this, it would be good for me.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can I get this result "example@example.com" from large file with python? Because it also contains many unnecessary "\n" characters.

Comment: If it's multiple addresses, it's reasonable not to call '\n' unnecessary

Comment: Yyou posted two different snippets and two different reg exps. Would be more useful to post snippet of your file (you can replace emails with garbage (like scramble domain names to make it non-existing, yet still syntactically correct) and then post the current script that you are having problems with otherwise it is confusing what is really a subject here.

Comment: give us a structure of your file to help you

Comment: @yavuzwb Are you having problems with your regex? If yes what exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: Is there data in the file other than email addresses?

Comment: @JibelSadeghi Yes, my problem is regex. The first code block is for a large file. The second code block was for a single email address. I was successful with second code block but I did not get same result with firs code block.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The file is contain only email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shot in the dark: because you said that matching `CC\nexample@example.com\n` results in `nexample@example.com`, I'll guess that your "`\n` characters" are not line breaks, but actual `\`s followed by `n`s. This can happen if somewhere in the pipeline the contents were incorrectly escaped, or if the text came from source code.

That would explain why your small example works with a hardcoded string, but not the text file: when you write `string = "CC\nexample@example.com\n"`, Python itself is replacing the `\n` characters with a linebreak. To simulate the contents of your text file, you should instead use `string = "CC\\nexample@example.com\\n"`.

If that's the case, you can either add a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to your regex, like `(?<\\n)rest_of_email_regex_here`.

Or more simply, do a preprocessing step of replacing all those characters with actual line breaks:

```
...
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\\n', '\n')
        emails = re.findall(email_regex, line)
        ...
```

If your text file really only contains `\n` and email addresses, after replacing the `\n` you can skip the regex and use `line.split()` to extract all addresses. This will return all sequences of non-space characters.